# How to press "search button" on softkeyboard emulator in Espresso Test Android Studio

Tags: android, android-espresso

How can I press the "search button" on the soft keyboard emulator in Espresso Test Android Studio? It's on the bottom right.

[screenshot of emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sibZT.jpg)

Answer (score 27):

Use the `pressImeActionButton()` ViewAction documented here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/action/ViewActions.html#pressImeActionButton()

```
onView(withId(R.id.search_box))
    .perform(pressImeActionButton());
```

In addition, you can use `hasImeAction (int imeAction)` documented here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html#hasImeAction(int) to check whether the expected IME action is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the layout file set property for EditText `android:imeOptions="actionSearch"`;
2. Then use the previous answer:

   onView(withId(R.id.search_box))
       .perform(pressImeActionButton());